# Trying to get Contacts for an Office 365 account using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of contacts for an Office 365 account using the Microsoft Graph API.  When I sign in using a hotmail account, everything works.  However, if I use an Office 365 account I get the following response error after calling "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts"

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidUser",
    "message": "The requested user 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com' is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f03da31a-a0d0-4095-9423-8992560c9b26",
      "date": "2017-08-09T20:37:16"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried searching for the error on Google but I am unable to find any information that will tell me why Office 365 accounts don't work.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks your 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com' is used with both a "Work or school account" and a "Personal account". You need to sign in with your Office 365/"Work or school account" to access its mail or contacts. The failed request was made with a token issued for a Personal account that uses the same email address as its identifier as your Office 365 account.
When signing in to our test app (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) you would be asked which account to want to use. The /beta/me/contacts request should work if you choose "Work or school account", but not when you choose "Personal account" (for that email address).

Comment: Many thanks!  Selecting Work or School account instead of Personal account worked.